# Examine the convergence of sequences and determine the limit function

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

I am self studying topology and I am trying to do this exercise about Vector Spaces which I have a hard time solving.

Let $\mathcal{C}([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of continuous real-valued functions in the interval [0,1]. For a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ we define
$$ ||f||_1 = \int^{1}_{0}|f(x)| dx.$$
Now consider in $\mathcal{C}([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ the sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ defined by:

$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1 - nx, & \text{for } 0\leq x \leq 1/n\\
0,      & \text{for } 1/n \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
\\
g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n-n^2x, & \text{for } 0\leq x \leq 1/n\\
0,      & \text{for } 1/n \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Now I must examine the convergence of each sequences and determine the limit function if convergent.

In this book I am working with, I can't find any theorem that could help me out on this one so I really hope any of you guys could help or just refer to some theorems!

Comment: Before referring to theorem, I would suggest that you start to compute $\Vert f_n \Vert_1$ and $\Vert g_n \Vert_1$ and the pointwise limits to look what happens.

Comment: Alright. So I Just did it. I found that $f_n$ has the limit function |-1/n| which converges towards 0 when n goes to infinity. And for $g_n$ I found that the limit function is 1/2. Meaning it converges towards 1/2 when n goes to infinity. Does this sound somehow correct and what do I do from here?

Comment: No this is not correct. Take $x = 1/3$. Can you tell us the values of $g_n(1/3)$ for $n=1, 2, \dots...$?

Comment: Well for $g_n(1/3)$ it would be 2/3, 2/3, 0, for $n=1,2,3$ and the rest of the sequence would be $0$.

Comment: So the limit is $0$. This contradicts your conclusion that $1/2$ is the limit of $(g_n)$. In fact you can prove that $g_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Though I can't compute it correctly. For $g_n(x)$ I compute it as following: $\int^{\frac{1}{n}}_{0} n-n^{2}x  dx = [nx-\frac{n^2}{2}x^2]^{\frac{1}{n}}_{0} = n\frac{1}{n} - \frac{n^2}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2}$ Which then converges to $1/2$ when n goes to infinity. Really sorry for not understanding it!

Comment: Sorry, I thought you where speaking of the pointwise convergence. Indeed you are close to it! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$(f_n)$ converges to $f=0$**

You have $$\Vert f_n - f\Vert_1 =\int_0^1 \vert f_n(x)\vert \ dx= \int_0^{1/n} (1-nx) \ dx =\left[x -\frac{nx^2}{2}\right]_0^{1/n}=\frac{1}{2n}$$
As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n}=0$, we get our conclusion $f_n \to 0$.

**$(g_n)$ doesn’t converge for the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ norm**

Suppose that $(g_n)$ converges to $g$ for the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ norm. Let’s prove that this implies $g=0$. For all $n \in \mathbb N$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\Vert g_n-g\Vert_1 &= \int_0^1 \vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert \ dx\\
&=\int_0^{1/n} \vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert \ dx + \int_{1/n}^1 \vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert \ dx\\
&=\int_0^{1/n} \vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert \ dx + \int_{1/n}^1 \vert g(x)\vert \ dx\\
&\ge \int_{1/n}^1 \vert g(x)\vert \ dx
\end{aligned}$$

Moving $n \to \infty$ we get $0 \ge \int_0^1 \vert g(x) \vert \ dx$. As $g$ is supposed to be a continuous function, we get $g=0$. But this in contradiction with $\Vert g_n \Vert =1/2$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.